# Django send_mail. SMTPNotSupportedError at /send_email/ SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server

Tags: python, django, smtp, vps, mail.ru

Доброго времени суток!

Столкнулся с ошибкой `SMTPNotSupportedError at /send_email/ SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server` при отправке письма на email на `Django` с помощью `send_mail`.

На моём ПК всё прекрасно работает, а на `VPS` выходит такая ошибка. На разных сайтах пишут что-то про `telnet AUTH LOGIN`, **но вот что выводит мне telnet:**

```
telnet smtp.mail.ru 25
Trying 217.69.139.160...
Connected to smtp.mail.ru.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 relay.v.fozzy.com ESMTP Exim 4.94.2
ehlo <DOMEN>.ru
250-relay.v.fozzy.com Hello <DOMEN>.ru [<IP-ADDRESS>]
250-SIZE 20971520
250-8BITMIME
250-PIPELINING
250-PIPE_CONNECT
250-CHUNKING
250-STARTTLS
250 HELP
```

То есть нет той самой команды AUTH. И ещё я не совсем понимаю, что вставлять за место `<DOMEN>`.

**Вот мои настройки send_mail в Django:**

```py
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'

EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.mail.ru'
EMAIL_PORT = 25
EMAIL_HOST_USER = '<EMAIL>'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '<PASSWORD>'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = '<NAME IN ENGLISH>'
```

**Вот мой упрощённый код:**

```py
message = '<MESSAGE>'
html = '<HTML_MESSAGE>'
to = '<EMAIL_TO>'

send_mail(subject='<SUBJECT>', message=message, from_email=f"{settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL} <{settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER}>", recipient_list=[to], html_message=html)
```

Может это проблема в моём VPS хостинге?

Если знаете решение или можете дать полезный совет, то пишите. Заранее спасибо

Comment: Пароль правильный так как на моём ПК всё работает аналогичным паролем и Email. А вот порт вы имеете в виду 465? Сейчас попробую - скажу.

Comment: также хочу уточнить вы разрешили доступ приложениям к вашей почте? [пример google](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps)

Comment: Не могу найти, как это сделать на mail.ru

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я как понял вы используете не тот порт [(здесь можно посмотреть порт)](https://help.mail.ru/mail/mailer/popsmtp) , также возможно не правильный пароль. Наверное вы смотрели порт из ответов mail.ru (но там ответ был дан 8 лет назад) :D. Всегда смотрите на официальном сайте!!!

Comment: Спасибо. Ну да, наверное, всё-таки неправильный порт, но теперь ошибка ``502 Bad Gateway``. Что это может значить не подскажете?

Comment: @Ger-ych, [попробуйте по инструкции](https://www.dmosk.ru/miniinstruktions.php?mini=smtp-telnet). Вместо домена попробуйте вставить `smtp.mail.ru` или ip адрес mail почты